# My stuff disappears when I log off multiplayer mode in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My wife and I are playing Minecraft over Lan, and whenever she logs off, we lose everything in her inventory. Why does this happen and how can we stop it?

Comment: M not sure if this might be part of the cause, but are you opening a single player game to multiplayer over LAN or using a dedicated server?

Comment: single player game to multiplayer over LAN.

Comment: My gut feeling is that's what's causing it.  It wouldn't surprise me if the game only saves your state, and not those of anyone else joining, since it's still technically a single player world.

Comment: Did it always do that? Is it a new thing from and update? We don't remember having the issue before.

Comment: I don't know, I've never opened a game to LAN.  When playing with friends/family, it was always on a dedicated server.

Comment: This is strange. Whenever I play over a LAN world with some of other friends, their progress is saved, along with everything else.

Comment: So what could be happening in our game?

Comment: Does she play with a separate account? It might be problematic for your server to sync if it's not a separate account or one properly logged in to the minecraft logon server.

Comment: it is separate accounts. She has her own log in and everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The person who opens to LAN must quit the game gracefully. That is, they first need to return to the main menu before closing the game. Abruptly quitting the game with the X button makes the game unable to save the world and player data.

Comment: This is true.  For multiplayer sessions, the game data is saved on the server, whether the server is hosting over the internet or over LAN.  In either case, the server will not be able to save data if it quits abruptly.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem tonight too. My wife logged onto a LAN game I was hosting, but instead of having all her gear, she had nothing.

So I opened the game appdata file for the world and looked at the player data. It showed three files:

- One hadn't been played in 24 hours (Which I assume was hers)
- One had logged off 5 minutes ago (Which I assume was the bad file)
- One had just logged off (Which I assume is mine)

To fix it, I moved the 24hrs file to my desktop, renamed it to the same name as the 5 minute file, then deleted the the 5 minute old file. Finally I moved the 24hr file back into the folder.

I loaded up my world, set it to be LAN accessible, and had the wife log on. Poof, she had her stuff back.

Comment: This is a valid answer from the looks of it, but the format is... not the most optimal in regards to conveying info. You think you could edit your answer so it's easier to follow every single step? Maybe add a table or divide into paragraphs; Whatever floats your goat.

Answer (score 1):

If the Minecraft LAN is hosting on you, She needs to go to main menu then quit the game.
If the Minecraft LAN is hosting on your wife, and she wants to exit, You need to go to main menu, and then she go to the main menu. Then its saved! Now you can Exit!

**To clarify what I am saying:** If you are the one who did "Open to LAN", she needs to quit first, if she did "Open to LAN", you need to quit first.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve experienced this problem too. I found it was an internet issue. My girlfriend and I are full time nomads with intermittent cell reception. We’ve found that when she logs in without signal, she has a completely different version of her character, with different levels and inventories. When we have signal, again, her character has its own levels and separate inventory. Sometimes, the two copies log in at different locations, based on where she logged out.