# Very strange minecraft death

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, nintendo-switch

Im on nintendo switch and I was playing minecraft with my brother (crossplay), mining in a cave. I clicked the home button to pause the game. We're not playing on realms so my brother was kicked from the game.

A little later I rejoined on my own spawned by my bed with no loot, exp, and reset hunger and health. The chat said nothing about the death(not even "*<username>* died").

My brother rejoined later in the game and he was still in the cave while my loot was beside him, he didn't die. What happened!? How can I stop it from happening again?

Comment: Can you make that an answer?

Comment: Done! I removed my old comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a fellow Nintendo Switch player, I would advise you to always save and quit properly. While going to the home menu does suspend the app, the game still runs the world for a little while before actually stopping the game fully (about 5 minutes is my guess, but Minecraft is always slow and buggy anyway on the Switch :p). As the game is still kind of unstable on the Switch, it may kick to the main menu, and other unexpected behaviors may occur upon returning (nothing major, just freezing and UI glitches, and reloging into the game should fix that).

On a side note, your brother was kicked since the Switch stops online activity when suspending an application. So, he was forced out while you stayed logged in. If you by chance were kicked to the main menu, or you quit the app before you played again, then the chat would have nothing to say since the chat clears on the client when you exit a world or server. I assume that your stuff is still there because it is in an unloaded chunk. So, mobs would despawn, and your stuff would stay until a player enters the chunk (in this case your brother. I would have him pick up your stuff for now if you were far away.

All in all, the Switch version can be buggy at times, so try your best to save and quit to make sure nothing happens. And as a tip, if you are ever on a realm or server, make sure to log off in a safe place, as you do stay half logged in for about 5 minutes, and things can kill you.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen situations where, if the server shuts down unexpectedly, player data files can be corrupted. When rejoining the world, the game treats your inventory as if it's a new player

Answer (score 2):

The only rational answer I can think of is that **while you were leaving, a creeper might have been tracking you and exploded while you were leaving the game.** You can still die after leaving the server, as it takes a little bit for the system to update that you are leaving, due to slight ping. Additionally, the chat resets the messages every time you leave the server, so that's why there was no death message.

Comment: I was wearing full diamond armor, and I was near a crafting table and furnace. When my brother joined I knew there was no crater because the table and furnace weren't broken on his screen.

Comment: @Dabbingsdednow Here's most likely the reason why. You must leave the game gracefully, or errors and corruption can happen: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/172796/267115